# How to group only words, no spaces?

Tags: regex, split

I want group all words without white space e.g.:

I like stackoverflow
[0]I
[1]like
[2]stackoverflow

Comment: Can you think of any other example strings? If it's just words separated by whitespace then you'll probably just want to use a `split()` function or equivalent (which most languages have). It would almost certainly be easier, although I don't know what language you're doing this in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)
```

In Java you would use something like this

```
String[] splits = "I like stackoverflow".split("\\s+");
// split[0] = "I"
// split[1] = "like"
// split[2] = "stackoverflow"
```

Comment: i need a group without white space, and without limit

Comment: @Stefhan, with pure regular expressions you can't group without limit. Every group must be known before. The split function does a repeated regex match.

Answer (score 3):

In Perl:

```
my $str = "I like stackoverflow";
my @words = split '\s+', $str;
```

`@words` now contains "I", "like", and "stackoverflow".

Answer (score 1):

What language are you using?

PHP:  $array=array_filter(array_map('trim',explode(" ",$string)));

or better yet:

or better yet.    $array=array_filter(array_map("trim",explode(" ",preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $copy))));

In action at one of my [dev sites](http://craigslist.fatherstorm.com/array_break.php)

Comment: i need a group without white space

Comment: THis will: Split on spaces, trim out any doublespaces, drop out any empty indexes in outward working order.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can use `\w` for an alphanumeric character so if you don't have strange symbols you can just go with something like

```
(\w)+\s+(\w)+\s+.....
```

where `\s` means any whitespace character

If you have words that are made also by symbols (even if it's quite nonsense) you can use `\S` instead that `\w` to match everything except white space.. but if you have just a list of words separated by spaces you can define a set of delimiters and split the string with an API function.

Comment: with this regex will match whitespace and, will group limited number of words

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg = /([\w$])+/gi; // matches only words without space and noalphabetic characters
```

Comment: Whilst this may be an answer it is just a piece of code with no explanation. When answering an old question that already has an accepted answer you need to add significant extra new information and an explanation of why your new answer is useful.

Comment: It's the shortest and simplest one solution (as i think). "\\matches only words without space and noalphabetic characters" - it explains all code here.